# Is _TexelSize suffix also available in Unity's compute shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, textures, compute-shader

According to the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html), in shader code we can get the size of a texture with variables named in `{TextureName}_TexelSize`. I tried but failed when writing compute shader. So I wonder if it's because the `_TexelSize` suffix doesn't work in compute shader?

**What I've tried is as follows.**

I defined the following two variables in my compute shader

```
Texture<float4> _MyTexture;
float4 _MyTexture_TexelSize;
```

and set _MyTexture in C# code

```
ComputeShader myComputeShader;
Texture2D myTexture;
// ...
myComputeShader = myComputeShader.SetTexture(0, "_MyTexture", myTexture);
```

I've also tried to change the type of `_MyTexture` to `sample2D` but it doesn't work.

**My goal** is to get the size of `_MyTexture` with `_MyTexture_TexelSize` in shader code without setting it in C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value manually:

```
myComputeShader.SetVector("_MyTexture_TexelSize", new Vector4(1.0f / myTexture.width, 1.0f / myTexture.height, myTexture.width, myTexture.height));
```

Comment: Yes. I can set the value in C# code manually. But I just wonder whether I can get the size without setting it, just like writing general shader.

Comment: In the compute shader, you have to set the value manually. Unity does not do this automatically.